# Tests in context menu of RSpec folder in RubyMine 6.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubymine

I’m using RubyMine 6.3 for Rails 3.2 project.

At first, in a context menu of RSpec folder in Project panel I was able to choose from the list which test I’d like to run. I've chosen "Run 'all tests in spec: …' " by mistake and now it is an only option in the context menu.

How could I change context menu option from "Run 'all tests in spec: …' " to "Run 'all specs in spec: …' " or at least reset it to default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the "run" menu. You should see an option that lets you edit configurations. If you remove all the configurations that exist for the item you are testing then ruby mine will use the default to create a new configuration the next time you run a test.

Comment: This has long been a source of frustration for me. It was impossible to find in the RubyMine docs. Thanks!